# Which are the undeniable Google Play Services permissions?

Tags: permissions, google-play-services, cyanogen-os

I just got a new phone (Wileyfox Swift) with Cyanogen 13.0 installed and I am playing a bit with the app permissions.

I am trying to understand which permissions can be denied to Google Play Services and which not.
After messing up a couple of times with my phone, I think it's a good idea to ask around if anyone has an idea about it... so at least I could avoid to factory reboot once more! :)

Comment: Google Play services is pretty much the front end of all things Google on your phone, so  playing around with it's permissions can have unexpected outcome in some other part of OS/ app - so it's best to leave it as it is - my 2 cents

Comment: @beeshyams Say that I use the standard Cyanogen permission lock. Then some windows pop up asking for location, SMS and contacts. I deny all requests, but then the system freezes and reboots and needs a factory reset. Shouldn't it be that at least the standard lock has been tested in a way that the phone (out from factory, without any additional app) works anyway?

Comment: I can't answer that..sorry